# applying a function recursively to each element

Tags: clojure

```
(def v [:1 :1 :1  :2 :2 :2 :3 :3])
(defn groupFirstElem [[vec & more :as myList]]
  (split-with (partial = vec) myList)
)
;the (groupFirstElem v) yields [(:1 :1 :1) (:2 :2 :2 :3 :3)]
```

the idea is to use groupFirstElem function to obtain this

```
[(:1 :1 :1) (:2 :2 :2) (:3 :3)]
```

how do i go about recursevely calling groupFirstElem so that it applies to each "group" of v without having to evaluate the first element twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your specific problem can be solved using:

```
(partition-by identity [:1 :1 :1 :2 :2 :2 :3 :3])
;; => ((:1 :1 :1) (:2 :2 :2) (:3 :3))
```

Back to your question; the following would repeatedly replace the last element of a sq with the (spliced) result of a function:

```
(defn iterate-last
  [f sq]
  (loop [sq sq]
    (if (empty? (last sq))
      (butlast sq)
      (recur (concat (butlast sq) (f (last sq)))))))
```

A small caveat, you have to call it like this:

```
(iterate-last groupFirstElem [v])
;; => ((:1 :1 :1) (:2 :2 :2) (:3 :3))
```

Comment: Thank you i had this a similar idea but dint know about  empty? or butlast, or last lol